# addclass in jquery parameter to be a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to dynamically calculate  the percentage value and pass the percentage value to add class prefixing 'p' to it. For every value of it i have a css class existing in my css file.

Please help find a way to do so.

```
    ac.sumPer=((ac.sum/5)*100);
    ac.test='p'+ac.sumPer;
    console.log(ac.test);

    $('#change').addClass("c100 big dark ac.test");
```

Comment: `$('#change').addClass("c100 big dark" + ac.test);`

Comment: [How to use javascript variables in jquery selectors](//stackoverflow.com/q/5891840), [jQuery: using a variable as a selector](//stackoverflow.com/q/17097947)

Comment: You can use `addClass()` multiple times i.e.`$('#change').addClass("c100 big dark" ).addClass(ac.test); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can use `addclass()` with variable names. Below is also the image when you inspect using dev tools.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var classname ="text";
 $('p').addClass("paragraph "+ classname);
})
```

```css
.paragraph{
  font-weight:bold;
}
.text{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
Hello There
</p>
```

[image]

For you case the code should be:

```
ac.sumPer=((ac.sum/5)*100);
ac.test='p'+ac.sumPer;
console.log(ac.test);

$('#change').addClass("c100 big dark "+ac.test);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try bellow. If you pass variable in double quote then its value will not be replaced.

```
ac.sumPer=((ac.sum/5)*100);
ac.test='p'+ac.sumPer;
console.log(ac.test);

$('#change').addClass("c100 big dark "+ ac.test);
```